# Cannot Access a closed stream error during Authentication on Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, http, xamarin

I've got an app made with Mobile Blazor Bindings. After few months I added new features but today while testing I see that my Login page doesn't work anymore. I have not changed the flow for the login page and related classes. This still works in iOS but on Android it says `Cannot Access A Closed Stream`

I'm asking this question because every duplicate of this question were about file sending and most of them using MemoryStream. I don't do that in this particular case.

#### 1st: You're redirected to Login Page:

```
@page "/login"
@layout AuthLayout
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject MyApp.Security.CustomStateProvider authStateProvider

<EditForm class="form-signin" OnValidSubmit="(() => OnSubmit())" Model="loginRequest">
    
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    <!--- 2 Text inputs for username and password --->
    <label class="text-danger">@error</label>
</EditForm>

@code{
        
    LoginRequest loginRequest { get; set; } = new LoginRequest() { RememberMe = false };
    string error { get; set; }

    async void OnSubmit()
    {
        error = null;
        try
        {
            await authStateProvider.Login(loginRequest);
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2nd: Your Login Info sent via Service

(AuthStateProvider):

```
 public class CustomStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IAuthService api;
    private CurrentUser _currentUser;
    HttpClient http = AppState._http;
    
    public CustomStateProvider(IAuthService api)
    {
         this.api = api;
    }
 
   public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
       // 
    }

    private async Task<CurrentUser> GetCurrentUser()
    {
       //
    }

    public async Task Logout()
    {
        //
    }

    public async Task Login(LoginRequest loginParameters)
    {
       await api.Login(loginParameters);
       NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }
}
```

#### 3rd The Request

```
public class AuthService : IAuthService
    {   
        HttpClient _httpClient = AppState._http; // Here _http is static HTTPClient where base URI is my server's URL.


   public async Task Login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
        {
            var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/login", loginRequest);
            if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) throw new Exception(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }

    // other methods 

}
```

At the  `var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/login", loginRequest);` I've got this cannot access to closed stream error.

```
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureNotClosed () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs:121 
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Length () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs:333 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.GetComputedOrBufferLength () [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs:497 
  at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders.get_ContentLength () [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpContentHeaders.cs:82 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SetupRequestBody (Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request) [0x00061] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SetupRequestInternal (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URLConnection conn) [0x00251] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0024c] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 
  at CugemderApp.Security.AuthService.Login (CugemderApp.Shared.Models.LoginRequest loginRequest) [0x00059] in C:\Users\bkaan\Desktop\novartz yedek\CugemderMobileApp\CugemderApp\Security\AuthService.cs:38
```

---

### What I Tried So Far

I've tried to send a POST Request to same endpoint with POSTMAN and it received 200 OK. Also iOS devices can login successfully.

So only thing that I tried is that changing `<EditForms>`'s `OnValidSubmit` to different things.

At first it was like this:

- `OnValidSubmit="OnSubmit"`
- Then `OnValidSubmit="( () => OnSubmit())"`
- I also tried `OnValidSubmit="( async () => await OnSubmit())"`

I suppose this is not the issue. I also run the web api project locally and it works on android too.

So in summary when I run the server project locally I can access from every client. But my deployed project where I can access from "http://api.xxxx.com/" is not accessible from android devices.

What is it that I miss? What might be the problem here?

---

Btw if anyone is wondering here is the Controller's Login method

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginRequest request)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);
            if (user == null) return BadRequest("Can't find use");
            var singInResult = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, request.Password, false);
            if (!singInResult.Succeeded) return BadRequest("Wrong password or not confirmed");

            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, request.RememberMe);
            return Ok();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Turns out updating the nuget packages solves the problem. System.Text.Json and HTTP packages had problems. I had to restore NuGet packages. Deleted everything in {UserName}/.nuget folder and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

After Android 9.0 , if you want to access Http request .You need to add the line `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in **Manifest.xml** like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app11">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="App11.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer but I've already have CleartextTraffic on true. Otherwise you can't even make a request to server app running locally.

Comment: Did you test some public http url ?